# What is the difference between ccScaleBy and ccScaleTo in cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am scaling my sprite object in cocos2d using the CCScaleTo method. It is not perfect scaling so I use this code:

```
id action1=[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.5 scale:1.25];
id action2=[CCScaleBy actionWithDuration:0.5 scale:.25];
id action3=[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.5 scale:1.25];
id action4=[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.5 scale:.25];

[timeUpImg runAction:[CCSequence actions:action1,action2,action3,action4,nil]];
```

This is working perfectly.

I don't know the difference between `ccScaleBy` and `CCScaleTo` and also how to use the "reverse" method. Can someone explain it please?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`CCScaleTo` scales the node/sprite to an absolute scale factor while `CCScaleBy` scales it by a factor relative to current scale.

For example, suppose a node currently has scale `0.25`:

- `[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.5 scale:2.0]` will modify the scale to `2.0` (simply ignores the current scale)
- `[CCScaleBy actionWithDuration:0.5 scale:2.0]` will modify the scale to `0.5` (0.25 * 2.0)

On the second question, the `reverse` method returns an instance of `CCAction` subclass that gives the reverse effect of the original action. For example: `[[CCScaleBy actionWithDuration:0.5 scale:2.0] reverse]` will return `[CCScaleBy actionWithDuration:0.5 scale:0.5]`, and `[[CCScaleBy actionWithDuration:0.5 scale:4.0] reverse]` will return `[CCScaleBy actionWithDuration:0.5 scale:0.25]`